# Trying to determine the top 70 percent of purchases using mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a scenario where I am trying to count the number of products purchased where the sum of the product purchases = 70% of the total purchases in MySQL.

In other words, how many unique products represent the top 70 percent of product purchases.

Consider the following example:

```
create table purchases
(id int not null auto_increment primary key,
`product`varchar(10),
`purchased` int);

insert into purchases values 
(1,'pen',1),(2,'pencil',5),(3,'pencil',5),
(4,'eraser',3),(5,'case',1),(6,'case',1),
(7,'pen',1),(8,'pen',1),(9,'pen',1),(10,'pen',1);
```

As you can see, I have 10 separate purchases of 4 unique products.

In total, there are 20 products purchased: 10 pencils, 5 pens, 3 erasers and 2 cases.

What I am trying to determine is how many products does it take to make up 70% of the total purchases. So in this case the desired result is 2.

The 2 comes from the 10 pencils plus the 5 pens = 15 = ~70% OF 20.

I have created a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/810767/4) at if it is of any help.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks,
Pete

Comment: You've not provided a link to the sqlfiddle, and the question's results seem a bit arbitrary; the correct result could just as easily be the pencils, erasers, and cases together.

Comment: Sorry, here is the link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/810767/4. I guess that it is a bit arbitrary but it should be based on the sum purchased descending. This is a simplistic example of the real world situation but if I can get this working, It will show me the path.

Comment: I think he is looking for the minimum number of unique products. Basically, start summing up from the item with the biggest amount of items orders and continue until you hit the 70% mark or more.

Comment: That makes it clearer. Off the top of my head, the closest you can get without some serious (and potentially unreliable) use of session variables is the get the sums of each product, ordered by sum descending and the go through the results in code to grab the rows until you reach your target criteria.

Comment: Ultimately, I am trying to write a mysql stored procedure that returns the count of unique products comprising 70% of the total purchases if that has any impact on the suggested solution.

Comment: Is this to test the [80-20](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_principle) rule?

Comment: @Uueerdo as the 'right' idea.  And `@variables` should work.  But, as he/she points out, it may be easier in client code, not SQL.

Comment: It is to be used in pursuit of best practices within a specific industry. Apparently in this industry, for certain sizes of businesses, there is a 'best practice' standard for the number of items that it takes to make up 70% of the total purchases. The lower this number is, the greater the negotiating power of the vendor to provide the best pricing to the customer.

Comment: @RickJames If he is shooting for a stored procedure, it should be fine. It just seems a lot of people try to do such things in "one query".

Comment: One or two nested subqueries, plus a `HAVING` (to filter out rows after the 70%) can probably do it in a 'single' query.  But it makes my brain hurt.  Add another nesting to get just the `COUNT(*)`.

Comment: Any help on the query and nested sub-queries would be a huge help. I am new to this and jumping into the deep end on this one.

Comment: Assuming the "deep end" you are referring to is databases and not programming in general, you are better off looking into creating a stored procedure as you originally planned. I'd write it as answer for you, but don't have the time at the moment, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User variables and some subqueries can be helpful to achieve what you want.

First, you need to know the total purchases; then you need to write a query that accumulates the purchases and "flags" the products that you want. Something like this:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dddbb/2)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table purchases (
  id int not null auto_increment primary key,
  `product`varchar(10),`purchased` int
);

insert into purchases 
values (1,'pen',1),(2,'pencil',5),(3,'pencil',5)
     , (4,'eraser',3),(5,'case',1),(6,'case',1)
     , (7,'pen',1),(8,'pen',1),(9,'pen',1)
     ,(10,'pen',1);
```

**Query 1**:

```
-- First, store "sum(purchased)" and the desired percentile into user variables
select sum(purchased), 0.7
into @total_purchases
   , @percentile
from purchases
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dddbb/2/0)**: (none)

**Query 2**:

```
-- Test the query: This will "flag" the desired records
select p.*
     , @cummulative := @cummulative + sum_purchased as cummulative
     , @cummulative / @total_purchases as cummulative_p
     , @cummulative / @total_purchases <= @percentile as flag
from 
    (
        select @cummulative := 0
    ) as init,
    (
        select product, sum(purchased) as sum_purchased 
        from purchases 
        group by product 
        order by sum_purchased desc
    ) as p
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dddbb/2/1)**:

```
| product | sum_purchased | cummulative | cummulative_p | flag |
|---------|---------------|-------------|---------------|------|
|  pencil |            10 |          10 |           0.5 |    1 |
|     pen |             5 |          15 |          0.75 |    0 |
|  eraser |             3 |          18 |           0.9 |    0 |
|    case |             2 |          20 |             1 |    0 |
```

**Query 3**:

```
-- Get the final result: Use the above query as a data source for your final result
select product, sum_purchased
from
  (
    select p.*
         , @cummulative := @cummulative + sum_purchased as cummulative
         , @cummulative / @total_purchases as cummulative_p
         , @cummulative / @total_purchases <= @percentile as flag
    from 
        (
            select @cummulative := 0
        ) as init,
        (
            select product, sum(purchased) as sum_purchased 
            from purchases 
            group by product 
            order by sum_purchased desc
        ) as p
  ) as a
where flag = 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dddbb/2/2)**:

```
| product | sum_purchased |
|---------|---------------|
|  pencil |            10 |
```

---

---

***Another way:***

If you want to force the inclusion of the first product that "breaks" the percentile barreer, you can try this (similar) approach:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dddbb/6)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table purchases (
  id int not null auto_increment primary key,
  `product`varchar(10),`purchased` int
);

insert into purchases 
values (1,'pen',1),(2,'pencil',5),(3,'pencil',5)
     , (4,'eraser',3),(5,'case',1),(6,'case',1)
     , (7,'pen',1),(8,'pen',1),(9,'pen',1)
     ,(10,'pen',1);
```

**Query 1**:

```
-- First, store "sum(purchased)" and the desired percentile into user variables
select sum(purchased), 0.7
into @total_purchases
   , @percentile
from purchases
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dddbb/6/0)**: (none)

**Query 2**:

```
-- Test the query: This will "flag" the desired records
select p.*
     , @cummulative := @cummulative + sum_purchased as cummulative
     , @cummulative / @total_purchases as cummulative_p
     , @flag as flag
     , @flag := case when @cummulative / @total_purchases > @percentile then 0 else 1 end as new_flag
from 
    (
        select @cummulative := 0
             , @flag := 1
    ) as init,
    (
        select product, sum(purchased) as sum_purchased 
        from purchases 
        group by product 
        order by sum_purchased desc
    ) as p
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dddbb/6/1)**:

```
| product | sum_purchased | cummulative | cummulative_p | flag | new_flag |
|---------|---------------|-------------|---------------|------|----------|
|  pencil |            10 |          10 |           0.5 |    1 |        1 |
|     pen |             5 |          15 |          0.75 |    1 |        0 |
|  eraser |             3 |          18 |           0.9 |    0 |        0 |
|    case |             2 |          20 |             1 |    0 |        0 |
```

**Query 3**:

```
-- Get the final result: Use the above query as a data source for your final result
select product, sum_purchased
from
  (
    select p.*
         , @cummulative := @cummulative + sum_purchased as cummulative
         , @cummulative / @total_purchases as cummulative_p
         , @flag as flag
         , @flag := case when @cummulative / @total_purchases > @percentile then 0 else 1 end as new_flag
    from 
        (
            select @cummulative := 0
                 , @flag := 1
        ) as init,
        (
            select product, sum(purchased) as sum_purchased 
            from purchases 
            group by product 
            order by sum_purchased desc
        ) as p
  ) as a
where flag = 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dddbb/6/2)**:

```
| product | sum_purchased |
|---------|---------------|
|  pencil |            10 |
|     pen |             5 |
```

Comment: Thanks! I guess that I just need to add to the query to get the count where the flagged =1? Also, the result that you got has the sum_purchased of 10 where the total purchased =20 so this only represents 50%?

Comment: `select @cumulative := 0` doesn't need to be a subquery, `SET @cumulative := 0;` could just be executed immediately before without adding that complication to the query.

Comment: @Uueerdo Indeed... but somehow when I tried that in SQL Fiddle, the rest of the results didn't show up, so I put it this way to create the full solution

Comment: @PeterBradstreet Yes, but as you can see, the next row ("pen") accumulates 75%, so its above the target value. You can, of course, redefine the flag condition (something like `floor(10 * @cummulative / @total_purchases) <= 10 * @percentile` might give you what you want)

Comment: @PeterBradstreet his logic does the cutoff at the last while below 70%.

Comment: Yes, I understand the logic. I think that the results in this case are skewed by the low number of items and purchases. In the real case scenario it will likely be less noticeable. I may play around with your floor idea though. Once again, thank you very much for the assistance.

Comment: @PeterBradstreet Check my edited answer... I think the second alternative gives you what you want

Comment: @PeterBradstreet Happy to help. By the way, if you find this post useful, please up-vote it (and if it solves your issue, accept it ;) )

Comment: Perfect! I am happy to up-vote it and accept it but am new to stackoverflow. How do I do that?

Comment: Figured out how to do that. Thanks again!